# Using Spring Security in Grails to restrict content access

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

Let me start off again again by saying that I am still new to Grails and Spring Security.  I have been doing my best to sift through the documentation and examples and samples.  It all has made me a bit confused or overwhelmed.

I am trying to use Spring to manage user access to information.  I have a site framed.  I want the admin to be able to add people, locations connected to the people and images of the locations. The picture is connected to the person.  I want the people that log-in to be able to see their pictures, only.

Is it better or best practice to do this with sec tags or @Secure annotations or a combination? Which is the most secure? I have restricted access using sec:tags. Is there a sec:tag I can use to select the pictures to be displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can look at this in a simpler way.  There are basically 3 ways to manage security with the basic plugin install.

- @Secured - This allows you to lock down access to an entire Controller and / or individual actions.  Think of this as locking down a URL to a specific set of roles.  Changes to this level of security will require a redeploy.
- Request Map - You get the same benefit as @Secured with the added bonus of being able to modify Controller / action security in a running environment vs having to do a redeploy.
- sec tags - These allow you to lock down the rendering of views.  For example, to allow an edit button to show up for one role while hiding it for another role.  The sec tags are used in combination with the above methods.

That's really basically it.  None of the above are more or less secure than the other.  What some people seem to confuse is the concept of "my data" and how Spring Security handles that.  If, in a Controller, you want a user to be able to access only their "pictures", you should just query for "pictures" based on the authenticated user.

```
def authenticatedUser = User.findByUsername(springSecurityService.principal.username)
def pictures = Picture.findAllByUser(authenticatedUser)
```

The view then only cares about what pictures you sent to it.  Each logged in user will then only see their pictures.  If the admin is logged in, and needs to see ALL the pictures, you might do something like this:

```
def authenticatedUser = User.findByUsername(springSecurityService.principal.username)
if (SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
   def pictures = Pictures.list() 
}
```

However, I'd probably just have a separate Controller for administrative purposes versus trying to do too much logic in one Controller.  Or, move the logic to a Service.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this does make sense and thanks!! It puts things into a better perspective.

Comment: OK so let me ask this.  I have my index page sec:tagged so that the admin can see the controllers to upload files create data and users.  Users have a username, password and location.  When a user logs in I want them to see the files that pertain to their location.  There can be multiple users attached to a location.  But I want every user with that location to see the associated files.  I stared with the @Secure but moved to the sec:tags.  Now I just need to limit the display of files based on location.  Any advice?

Comment: Start a new question.

Comment: New thread started "selecting content to display based on user in Grails with Spring Security"